# How to download list of files and rename them incrementally using wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I have a list which contains imgur links, I want to download the links from it and auto rename them with `wget.`

For example, these are the links in the list:

```
http://i.imgur.com/YSLB7eh.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/1SHYQHZ.jpg
```

I want to download them as img1.jpg and img2.jpg.

Comment: Does it have to be with `wget` only?

Comment: No, anything that can help is cool.

Comment: Are they all jpegs?

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: There ya go! See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this bash script (only works for .jpg). I know it's probably not the most elegant solution, but it should do the trick! Change `list.txt` to the name of your list file:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1
while read p; do
  wget -O "img${count}.jpg" $p
  count=$((count+1))
done <list.txt
```

**How do I use this?**

1. Create a new file where you want to download your images to, name it however you like, e.g. `downloadlist.sh`.
2. Add contents from script above to file, change `list.txt` to whatever your list file is called and save.
3. Make it executable using chmod:

   ```
   chmod +x downloadlist.sh
   ```
4. Execute the file and sit back while it processes:

   ```
   ./downloadlist.sh
   ```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. One more question, how would you rename the first 9 files like this img01.jpg img09.jpg?

Comment: The more kosher way of doing it is `while IFS=read line`.